# Passing parameters to SQLCommandText

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to execute pass parameters to a SQL INSERT statement via VB.NET:

```
Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conn)
                cnn.Open()
                Using insertTrans As SqlTransaction = cnn.BeginTransaction
                    Using cmd As SqlCommand = cnn.CreateCommand()
                        'skip 1st row
                        Dim firstRow As Boolean = True
                        For Each item As String In lines
                            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [matrixtest].[dbo].[SM_Fatca_GinList] VALUES (@gin, @name, @country)"
                            If Not firstRow Then
                                item = item.Replace(""" ,", """,")
                                item = item.Replace(", """, ",""")
                                item = item.Replace(""",""", """__||__""")
                                item = item.Replace("""", "")
                                fields = item.Split("__||__")
                                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fields(0)) Then
                                    If Not fields(0).Length = 0 Then
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gin", fields(0))
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", fields(1))
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", fields(2))
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                            firstRow = False
                            cmd.Transaction = insertTrans
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        Next
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
```

I am getting this error: `Must declare the scalar variable "@gin".`

This looks like a SQL error but why would I have to declare the variables in SQL don't I just use this syntax to pass the parameters? What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: You are conditionally adding the parameters. You must add the parameters whenever  the command text is set.

Comment: If you have more than 3 columns in the DB table, you should probably specify them in the SQL.  Otherwise it doesnt really know how to map them.  The main thing is that you are doing addwithvalue in a loop, so each time adds another @gin param and another and another....  Create the 3 params once and then just set/reset the value as you iterate Also, if `lines` is a still a list, `Lines.RemoveAt(0)` will remove the header instead of that bool

Comment: @Plutonix How do you create the params without setting them?

Comment: When `fileds(0)` is empty then you do not add the parameter `@gin`, but still you execute the command because of this line of code: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`. The execution then finds that there is no parameter of `@gin` set and therefore it throws an error.

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict - there is a fair amount there that wont compile.  `cmd.Parameters.Add("@gin", SqlDbType.???)` will add the param - do that outside the loop.  Inside, just set the new value: `cmd.Parameters("@gin").Value = fields(0)` and execute.  I would also advise you to scrub the data before it is time to add to the db

Comment: You could maybe try `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` just before your set of AddWithValue lines.  It might keep you from having to rework it all

Comment: @Plutonix your suggestion plus Sunil's answer resulting in it working

Comment: I would have posted an answer but there was too much there that would not compile, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding parameters only when a certain condition is true, so you must move the command execution to the same `if` in which you set parameter values. Otherwise, there will be situations when the command parameters are not set/added, but the command is still executed resulting in an error being thrown.

Change your code to what is given below.

```
If Not firstRow Then
    item = item.Replace(""" ,", """,")
    item = item.Replace(", """, ",""")
    item = item.Replace(""",""", """__||__""")
    item = item.Replace("""", "")
    fields = item.Split("__||__")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fields(0)) Then
        If Not fields(0).Length = 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gin", fields(0))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", fields(1))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", fields(2))
            //moved the below 3 lines to within this IF
            //this is necessary for missing @gin error to be not thrown
            firstRow = False
            cmd.Transaction = insertTrans
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gin", fields(0))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", fields(1))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("country", fields(2))`

Remove the @ when you make AddWithValue.